# Refresh rate revert on 60 Hz on reboot

Tags: 12.04, resolution, monitor

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 (upgrade from 11.10) and when I change monitor refresh rate everything is ok, until reboot, on reboot my refresh rate revert to 60 Hz. I found similar threads on Ask Ubuntu but answers are not good for me. Is there any way for making a script which change refresh rate using Nvidia settings, or can you help me to fix this using xrandr. 
Refresh rate should be 85 and resolution 1280x960. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set this for good in your xorg.conf file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Here is my Monitor section as an example:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1440x900"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "61"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection
```

You mentioned Nvidia, so I assume that is your graphics card. Are you using the proprietary drivers? I'm sure you have, but just in case: have you used the Nvidia Settings tool to set your display parameters?

I have recently had it recommended to use [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) on 12.04 to get the latest and greatest drivers, seems to be working well on both my Nvidia and ATI based systems.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "IBM G76"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 86.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 160.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

That's mine xorg file. I dont't have preferredMode and targetRefresh options like you have, can I add them manually, is it safe? I'm using NVidia graphic card with proprietary drivers.

Comment: and I used Nvidia-settings tool to set display parametres, and it works, but on reboot it revert to defaults, I also saved changed to xorg file under gksu.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a startup user process that changes your refresh rate to 85 Hz.

Create directory

: `$ mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user/ && cd ~/.config/systemd/user/`

Create a new service in the same directory

: `$ gedit refresh_rate_manager.service`

Paste the following in that service file.

```
[Unit] 
Description=Refresh Rate Manager Service

[Service] 
Type=simple ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'xrandr --rate 85'
User=<Enter your $USER here>

[Install] 
WantedBy=default.target
```

Perform a daemon reload and enable this service to be run at startup using systemctl:

```
$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
$ systemctl --user enable refresh_rate_manager.service
$ systemctl --user start refresh_rate_manager.service
```